# if statement with multiple conditions and only continue when both values is true or false

Tags: objective-c

I have the following scenario: 
I have 2 textfield, one to a persons name and another to an email input. 
I now what to validate on the inputs from the textfields, I do so with the use of "if statements" like so:

```
NSString *name = [self.defaults objectForKey:@"Name"];
NSString *email = [self.defaults objectForKey:@"Email"];

 if ([name length] > 0 && NSStringIsValidName(name) && [email length] > 0 && NSStringIsValidEmail(email) ) {

        //All is okay, proceed to main menu. 



    } else {


        if (!NSStringIsValidName(name)) {
            alertMessage = @"Your name is not valid"

        }else if ([name length] == 0) {


            alertMessage = @"Name not written. Please write a name in settings";

            NSLog(@"3 name not written");

        }else if (!NSStringIsValidEmail(email)) {

            alertMessage = @"Your email is not valid";

            NSLog(@"4 email not valid");
        }else if ([email length] == 0) {

            alertMessage = @"Email not written. Please write a name in settings";

            NSLog(@"5 email not written ");

        }


            alertMessage = @"Name and email is not written or is not valid";

            NSLog(@"1 all not valid");

        //Show Alert message.... 
    }
```

I now want to show the alertmessage if *only* both name and email is not written or valid, and then only show the alertmessage for the rest if their condition is met. With my current code the alert is showed twice. For example if both name and email is valid I get one message for them both and two for their individual if statements. How is it possible to `only`  perform an action if both values is true or false, in order to show one alert based on the condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it your first condition:

```
if (!NSStringIsValidName(name) && !NSStringIsValidEmail(email)) {
  alertMessage = @"Name and email is not written or is not valid";
  NSLog(@"1 all not valid");
} else if (!NSStringIsValidName(name)) {
  alertMessage = @"Your name is not valid"
} else if ([name length] == 0) {
  alertMessage = @"Name not written. Please write a name in settings";
  NSLog(@"3 name not written");
} else if (!NSStringIsValidEmail(email)) {
  alertMessage = @"Your email is not valid";
  NSLog(@"4 email not valid");
} else if ([email length] == 0) {
  alertMessage = @"Email not written. Please write a name in settings";
  NSLog(@"5 email not written ");
}
```